# D3js not rendering chart properly: Everything shows up as a line

Tags: angular, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm learning D3js and the following script only renders an SVG containing a vertical line. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a data item called Fight which contains a few pieces of data, including a property that gets all damage events in a game's log file and inserts them into an object of type `{ time: number, damage: number }`.

Times are represented in milliseconds.

```js
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {
  fight: Fight;

  svg: any;
  g: any;
  x: any;
  y: any;

  constructor(
    private readonly graphService: GraphService,
    private readonly hostElement: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.graphInit();

    this
      .graphService
      .fight
      .subscribe({
        next: fight => {
          this.fight = fight;
          this.graph();
        },
        error: error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
  }

  graphInit(): void {
    this.svg =
      d3
        .select(this.hostElement.nativeElement)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 200, 100].join(' '));
  }

  graph(): void {
    const data = this.fight.damage;

    const width = this.fight.timeElapsedMs;
    const height = this.fight.maxDamage + (this.fight.maxDamage * 0.05);

    // X and Y Axis for area charts
    this.x =
      d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.time))
        .range([0, width]);

    this
      .svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));


    this.y =
      d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.damage))
        .range([height, 0]);

    this
      .svg
      .append('g')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(this.y));

    this
      .svg
      .append('path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', '#a80000')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .attr('d',
        d3
          .line()
          .x((d: any) => this.x(d.time))
          .y((d: any) => this.y(d.damage))
      );
  }
}
```

Full Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/xoriworgv?file=src/app/shared/components/graph/graph.component.ts

It's an electron app so I'll see if I can put in some dummy data and make it work.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance of your code?

Comment: Yes, I will add it in a moment. This is an Electron app so I can't replicate full functionality.

Comment: I've added a stackblitz.

Comment: please share your stackblitz link -  i am not able to open the link. I hope you have replicated the issue in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deducted your problem without the Stackblitz link, with some made up sample data.

The problem is the way you treat your data. `d3.line()` expects an array of `n` points, each an object with an `x` and `y` coordinate. You only gave it `fight.damage`, which is an array of numbers. I created a function for you, `zip`, which you can easily use with TypeScript, to help transform the data.

Having done that, now you see more than a line!

```js
const graph = (fight) => {
  const svg =
    d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', '400')
    .attr('height', '250')
    .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 200, 100].join(' '));

  const line =
    d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => x(d.time))
    .y((d) => y(d.damage));

  const rawData = zip(fight.time, fight.damage);
  const data = rawData.map(([time, damage]) => ({
    time: time,
    damage: damage,
  }));

  const width = fight.timeElapsedMs;
  const height = fight.maxDamage + (fight.maxDamage * 0.05);

  // X and Y Axis for area charts
  const x =
    d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(fight.time))
    .range([0, width]);

  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  const y =
    d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(fight.damage))
    .range([height, 0]);

  svg
    .append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  svg
    .append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', '#a80000')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', line);
};

const fight = {
  damage: [50, 100, 50, 150],
  time: [100, 200, 300, 400],
  timeElapsedMs: 500,
  maxDamage: 100,
};

/**
 * zip is a javascript equivalent of the python zip function
 *
 * Example:
 * zip([1, 2, 3], [11, 22, 33]) => [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33]]
 *
 * @param {T[][]} rows An array of the rows to zip
 * @returns {T[][]} the zipped array
 */
//function zip<T>(...rows: T[][]): T[][] {
function zip(...rows) {
  return rows[0].map((_, col) => rows.map(row => row[col]));
}

graph(fight);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```